# Import svg Image to pdf

Tags: java, spring, database, svg, pdfbox

I am saving svg image on db as binary.I want to call it and draw it into a pdf file. But the PDFBox library I'm using doesn't support getting svg images from the database. And I also do not convert binary to file format so that I can convert to another image type. Is there any way to handle this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Like you said, PDFBox does not support svg format.
If you don't want to make conversion of the svg to a supported format, maybe you can try to use [this library](https://github.com/rototor/pdfbox-graphics2d), it might help you achieve your wanted result.

Comment: I am not able to convert svg image saved as binary to convert it to other image types. Do you know how to handle this problem?

Comment: try [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59561137/1909995). I'm sure there are more solutions.

Comment: @Ghost93 Sorry, I just took the weekend off, just checked your reply today. My problem is that the svg image is being stored in the database in binary form, I want to convert it to a format like png, jpg... so that it can be added to the pdf file. I can't find how to add svg images directly to pdf :(

Comment: So you question is really just how to feed `TranscoderInput` (from the link) some non-file input? If you have a byte array then use `ByteArrayInputStream`.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I tried, but still can't read the svg file. If can't read it, I can't convert to png or jpg...

Comment: First you should see whether the code works if you save your input into a file. If that works, then the problem is feeding your input into TranscoderInput , and you should create a question that shows the code you used, and mention what database you're using.

Comment: I will try, thanks